# Create string from list of lists then return it with #'s bordering the edges of the string

Tags: python, string, border

I'm having trouble writing this function which has to convert a list of lists to a string then surround it with borders. It also has to replace the # on the far right line that has string 'A" with '.' . This is the input and expected output

```
Input: [['.',   '.',    '.',    'e'],
        ['A',   'A',    '.',    'e'],
        ['.',   '.',    '.',    'e'],
        ['.',   'X',    'X',    'X'],
        ['.',   '.',    '.',    '.'],
        ['.',   'y',    'Z',    'Z']]

Output: ######
        #...e#
        #AA.e.
        #...e#
        #.XXX#
        #....#
        #.yZZ#
        ######
```

As you can see the line with the A's has a period at the end instead of '#' as this is one of the conditions of the function. Somehow it has to recognize which list has 1 or multiple A's and then replace the # on the end with a period. This is the code I have so far thanks for any help

```
def border_around(lst):
    new_value = ''.join(str(r) for v in lst for r in v)
    maxlen = max(len(s) for s in new_value)
    colwidth = maxlen + 2
    return '#' + '.'*colwidth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def border_around(lst):
    ncols = max(len(row) for row in lst)+2
    first = '#' * ncols + '\n'
    last = '\n' + '#' * ncols
    return first + '\n'.join('#'+''.join(row)+('#' if 'A' not in row else '.') for row in lst) + last
```

Comment: Thanks for a simple solution to this function

Comment: Do you know how I would have this print the bordered string rather then returning it? I'm trying to do troubleshooting but can't figure out how I would have this print a sample list of lists. When I change the return to print I get a syntax error

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Python 3, just do print(first + ...)

Comment: @RoryDaulton you're right, it doesn't, i misread the question

Comment: @RoryDaulton just edited my answer. Hope it works now

Answer (score 0):

Considering the rules of A, you can change:

```
return first + '\n'.join('#'+''.join(row) + '#' for row in lst) + last
```

to:

```
return first + '\n'.join('#'+''.join(row) + ('#' if 'A' in row else '') for row in lst) + last
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting this, for some reason I'm getting an invalid syntax error in python visualizer for this return statement Edit: I think I figured out the problem